# why is grub2 ignoring kernel options when boot from el torito on CD?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a simple manually created `grub.cfg` file, which I load into `grub-mkimage`, then build into an el torito image on an iso9660 iso.

Everything actually boots, but the kernel options are ignored completely.

My `grub.cfg`:

```
set default=0
set timeout=10

set gfxmode=auto
insmod efi_gop
insmod efi_uda

menuentry "MyOS" {
    search.fs_label SOMELABEL root
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux /boot/vmlinuz quiet
    initrd /boot/initrd
}
```

The above shows a single entry in the grub boot menu, if I edit it with `e` I see the correct configuration. But it definitely does not pass `quiet` to the kernel.

The image:

```
grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi -o EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI --config=boot/grub/grub.cfg --compression=xz disk part_msdos part_gpt linux loopback normal configfile search search_label true iso9660 efi_uga efi_gop gfxterm gfxmenu gfxterm_menu fat ls cat tar
```

And the EFI boot:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=efiboot.img bs=4k count=1000
mkfs.vfat efiboot.img
mount efiboot.img /mnt
cp -r EFI/ /mnt
unmount /mnt
```

And the iso (ignore the MBR lines):

```
xorriso -as mkisofs -l -J -R -V SOMELABEL \
  -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
  -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -c boot/isolinux/boot.cat \
  -ishybrid-mbr /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin \
  -eltorito-alt-boot -e efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
  -o some_output.iso .
```

All of the above as a gist: https://gist.github.com/deitch/260bb94ecf7932cb83bdf7024099fdb5

EDIT: Yes, I did enter the grub shell with `c` and try entering the properties manually. No luck.

Comment: You have typos I'm assuming .. it's umount not unmount, it's -isohybrid-mbr not ishybrid-mbr.
Also this should be fixed with newer kernels afaik.
Are you basing this on a guide btw? If so where? :)

Comment: Yeah, I know the typos, those are mostly manual copy-paste errors.